# looping credentials as array in webdriver java

Tags: java, loops, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm new to web driver. Please help me to loop login credentials as the array and loop it.

```
mean
usernames : a,b,c,d
passwords : 1,2,3,4
```

I have to loop it

```
String[] usernameArray={"John","Mary","Luke"};
String[] passwordArray={"jMan21","maree34","skywalker"};

if(username.equals(usernameArray) && password.equals(passwordArray)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome "+username+"\n"+"You are logged in as: "+logZone,"Log in",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect login or password","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? check if the first username in the array match the first password? check all the combinations? check it against another variable? something else?

Comment: i'm trying to check the login with different credentials.i have to loop and check the sign in with different credentials ( valid and non-valid )

Answer (score 0):

You can try and fit in your expected validations using the below code

```
String[] usernameArray={"John","Mary","Luke"};
String[] passwordArray={"jMan21","maree34","skywalker"};

        for(String username : usernameArray) {
            for(int i = 0;i<passwordArray.length;i++) {
                System.out.println(username + "  " + passwordArray[i]);
            }
        }
```